# Do Python and wxPython run on Windows 98?

Tags: python, wxpython, windows-98

I'm trying to write an application that should work both on Windows 98 and XP. I decided to go with Python, but I'm having trouble even installing it on Win'98 (Python 2.7 installer says something about missing features of Windows Installer, but AFAIK 2.0 is the latest Windows Installer version compatible with '98).

- Does anyone have a working Windows 98 environment with Python and wxPython? How did you make it work? I don't need Python 2.7, but a 2.4 or 2.5 would be nice.
- If not, what other high-level language would you suggest that is actively maintained, can display Windows widgets and works with Windows 98? (asm/C/C++ and other low-level languages are out of question -- this is a simple application whose main job is to display windows and dialogs).

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure we used Python2.4 and wxPython on '98 way back when.

I don't have a win98 machine to test it on, but it looks like at least [Python2.5.4](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/) binaries are available for win98

I think win98 support may have been [dropped](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/using/windows.html#installing-python) for 2.6

wxPython download page says this

> ### Microsoft Windows
>
> The Win32 version of wxPython is
>   distributed as a set of standard
>   self-installing executables. This
>   allows you the convenience of using
>   the Start Menu and Add/Remove Programs
>   just like any other Windows software.
>
> There are two versions of wxPython for
>   each of the supported Python versions
>   on Win32. They are nearly identical,
>   except one of them has been compiled
>   with support for the Unicode version
>   of the platform APIs. Unless you've
>   been told differently, you probably
>   want to get the Unicode build of
>   wxPython. Although they are not
>   nativly Unicode like NT-based systems,
>   the Unicode build of wxPython will
>   also mostly work on Windows 98/Me
>   systems using a Microsoft hack called
>   MSLU (or unicows.dll) that translates
>   unicode API calls to ansi API calls.
>   However the coverage of the API is not
>   complete so there are some difficult
>   bugs lurking in there, so the best
>   thing to do is to upgrade your
>   machines if possible, otherwise
>   Windows 98/Me users may want to try
>   the ANSI build instead.

and they are still release [installers for Python2.5](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.11.0-py25.exe)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Python droped Win9x/NT support at version 2.5.4.

However there are alternates builds: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/162317-python-27-for-windows-95/